# Angular service not updating subscribed components

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular-services

I have an Angular 2/4 service which uses observables to communicate with other components.

**Service:**

```
let EVENTS = [
    {
      event: 'foo',
      timestamp: 1512205360
    },
    {
      event: 'bar',
      timestamp: 1511208360
    }
  ];

@Injectable()
export class EventsService {

  subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(EVENTS);

  getEvents(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

  deleteEvent(deletedEvent) {
    EVENTS = EVENTS.filter((event) => event.timestamp != deletedEvent.timestamp);
    this.subject.next(EVENTS);
  }

  search(searchTerm) {
    const newEvents = EVENTS.filter((obj) => obj.event.includes(searchTerm));
    this.subject.next(newEvents);
  }
}
```

My `home` component is able to subscribe to this service and correctly updates when an event is deleted:

```
export class HomeComponent {

  events;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private eventsService: EventsService) { 
    this.subscription = this.eventsService.getEvents().subscribe(events => this.events = events);
  }

  deleteEvent = (event) => {
    this.eventsService.deleteEvent(event);
  }
}
```

I also have a root component which displays a search form. When the form is submitted it calls the service, which performs the search and calls `this.subject.next` with the result (see above). However, these results are not reflected in the `home` component. Where am I going wrong? For full code please see [plnkr.co/edit/V5AndArFWy7erX2WIL7N](https://plnkr.co/edit/V5AndArFWy7erX2WIL7N).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide a service multiple times, you will get multiple instances and this doesn't work for communication, because the sender and receiver are not using the same instance.

To get a single instance for your whole application provide the service in `AppModule` and nowhere else.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/p2Z8T7AMvgcxVcPJYDJ7?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Component is loaded through  or using its selector. I made a separate component and forgot to load it in the application.